# Web Service returning images? Best solution?

Tags: image, web-services

i'm wondering what's the best solution of returning images from a web service?
My previous enterprise project stores images on a server's hard drive.
1 - Make sure the image's name is distinctive by adding time stamp to name during uploading an image to server. 
2 - Store image name in web service
3 - get image by calling `'url + image name'`

Is it a good or bad solution? Or how do you implement this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you need a Restful or a Soap Web service?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create table (tblUploadFiles) in database for Upload files and that table should have at list following columns.

- FileId
- FileName
- FileStoreAt
- DateOfUpload
- FileType
- IsActive/IsDeleted
- OtherDetails

And Use Web Services to return any file with original name and If possible all files store at secure location.